# Css: How to format and remove outlining borders of table on left and right side?

Tags: html, css

I would like to remove the outlining borders from my table, i.e. the top, bottom, left and right border that is now in black 1px. I've tried to change in my css but it does only take away the borders from the whole table.

Also I would like to (ON HOVER) add a to the cells on the left hand, a left bold colored border. If that makes sense?
Like this: if I hover a row in the table (as it is now) it gets colored as intended. But I want the outermost left cell to also get a bold border on its left side.  This cell: `<td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>`

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Compare Table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%" class="hoverTable">
  <tr>
  <td class="blankcell"></td>
    <td id="check">Image</td>
    <td>Image</td> 
    <td>Image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td id="check">&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td id="x01">&#x2716</td>
    <td>&#x2716</td> 
    <td>&#x2716</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css:

```
th,td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.hoverTable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.hoverTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#fff;
}
/* Upper left cell*/
.blankcell {
    background: none!important; 
    border: none!important;
}
/* HOVER FUNCTION */
.hoverTable{
        width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse; 
    }
    .hoverTable td{ 
        padding:7px; 
        border: #000000 0px solid;
    }
    /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
    .hoverTable tr{
        background: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
    .hoverTable tr:not(:nth-child(1)):hover {
        background-color: #86D694;
    }
/* Check and X-Mark Coloring*/
#check {
    color: #1CF200;
}
#x01 {
    color: #ff6969;
}
```

I'm grateful for any help on this matter, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the css of the selected rows.

This will be your default css (which set the borders)

```
.hoverTable tr{
    background: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top:1px solid black;
}
```

This will be your css on hover

```
.hoverTable tr:not(:nth-child(1)):hover {
    border-left:5px solid black;
}
```

I have added an id for the top and bottom rows called `notop` and `last`

Updated HTML:

```
  <tr id = "notop">
  <td  class="blankcell"></td>
    <td id="check">Image</td>
    <td>Image</td> 
    <td>Image</td>
  </tr>


<tr  id = "last">
  <td class="rowTitle">TITLE</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td>
    <td>&#x2714</td> 
    <td>&#x2714</td>
  </tr>
```

CSS for the top and bottom rows

```
#notop{
    border:0px;
}
#last{
    border-bottom:0px;
}
```

*Check out the working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/2o144n92/*

Answer (score 0):

hello please use/try this

#### CSS

```
border-left
border-right
border-top
border-bottom
```

check this link [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-bottom-style)